# updated_at before created_at in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I noticed a few of my records have an 'updated_at' time several months prior to their 'created_at' time. Notice one of my records has:

```
created_at: "2015-05-12 13:52:53", updated_at: "2014-12-12 13:52:53"
```

I don't change or manipulate these values at all in my source code. Here is the migration file I used to create the table:

```
class CreateVisitors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visitors do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.references :page, index: true
      t.references :website, index: true
    end
    add_foreign_key :visitors, :pages
    add_foreign_key :visitors, :websites
  end
end
```

Visitors are a child of Websites and Pages. Websites have Pages, Pages have Visitors. Websites have Visitors through Pages.

I'm using the Visitors 'updated_at' values to monitor the time they are spending on a Page. When the 'updated_at' values are oddly incorrect, it gives strange values which messes up parts of the application.

Strange thing, is that some of the 'updated_at' values are referencing dates several months before I started the application.

I couldn't find any info on this issue, have any of you experienced this before?

Comment: And people say, there is nothing like time travelling :-P

Comment: Well either your server is extremely bad at telling time or maybe you accepting the `updated_at` param somewhere in your app and getting wrong values from the client. Or it involves time-traveling robots. Sexy  time-traveling robots.

Comment: Did you ever find the issue with this? I've seen the same myself recently on a couple of rouge records. Can't for the life of me figure what would be causing it.